# Having trouble recreating this card text?

Tags: flutter

I cant seem to get this quite right, any ideas how i can replicate this in flutter?[image]

[image]

You can see i cant quite get it right

Comment: Wrap the Text Widget with FittedBox. Put some code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```js
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () => print('feedback'),
  child: Card(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
    ),
    child: Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    right: 15.0),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor:
                    AppThemes.mainColorGreen,
                    radius: 30,
                    child: Icon(
                      MdiIcons.commentQuoteOutline,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 30,
                    ),
                  ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment:
                  CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Feedback',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
                        fontSize: 15,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Have any general feedback for our app? Let us know here!'),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
      ),
    ),
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
),
```